# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x}+be^{-x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

could someone help me to evaluate:$\lim_{x \to \infty} xe^{-x}+be^{-x} $

I know that the second half of the equation goes to zero because it is basically $b/(e^{\infty})$. but the first half of the equation becomes $\infty/e^{\infty}$ which is undefined. I know that the limit is zero for the whole thing but can I just ignore that undefined part of it?

Comment: L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: @simonzack is that where you take the derivative of the whole function and send it to infinity, cuz I have the derivative in front of me.

Comment: Yes that's what it's doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use l'Hopital's rule:
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac x{e^{x}}\stackrel{H}{=}
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac 1{e^{x}}=0\;\;.
$$

Comment: What does that H thing above the equals supposed to mean?

Comment: @Quantitative It shows where l'Hôpital is being used; recall that this is a “conditional” equality: if the right hand side limit exists, then equality holds.

Answer (score 3):

From the power series for
$e^x$:

$e^x
=1+x+x^2/2+...
> x^2/2
$
so
$xe^{-x}
< 2/x
\to 0
$.